# Is there an emulator frontend that can show multiple roms at once?

Tags: emulator, frontend

I'm building an arcade cabinet, and found the "AdvanceMENU" frontend:

[image]

Those are just snapshots, I'm wondering if there exists a frontend that would show the real start-up screens of the games. Given today's computers' computing power, I don't think they would have any problems generating 12 small games at once.

Does such a frontend exists ? It could be either Windows or Linux, no preference.

And, of course, I own the games I want to put in the cabinet.

Comment: +1 for bulding an arcade cabinet.  I hope you are going to include Golden Axe.

Comment: +1 for a really cool question. I don't have an answer, but I'm very interested. Good on you for the cabinet and good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I'm starting to think that such a frontend doesn't exists. I saw a screenshot once, I guess it was just screenshots, and I mistook it for an emulator running multiple games. Someone should code it ^^;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the benefit to emulating a bunch of games all at once compared to the cost just doesn't make it onto emulator/front-end developer's radar.

However AdvanceMENU supports [MNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple-image_Network_Graphics). So, you could capture the opening portion of each given game and then have animated tiles.

In fact, the majority of front-ends support video or animated graphics for their thumbnails to some extent. So you could easily have the illusion that each game was constantly going through its start sequence. Alternatively you could just showcase each games gameplay.